# For what value of '$a$' the given equation is positive .

Tags: linear-algebra

We have to find for what values of '$a$' does  $x^2+y^2-2axy>0$    holdes?

solution i tried: first i make a matrix of this equation

\begin{pmatrix}
 1& -a\\ -a&1 
\end{pmatrix}

now the given matrix is symmetric and we can i apply definition of positive definite matrix here.

So for symmetric matrix to be positive definite its determinant  should be positive .   now i take determinent of matrix which is $1-a^2$

now solving  $1-a^2>0$ we get answer $ \left |a  \right |<1$

now the question is does the method i applied is right ?I  applied a linear algebra formula here ,i have doubt about my method,  If someone has some another method please suggest me .

Thank you.

Comment: This is the best, quickest way to do it in this case. This is Sylvester's Criterion and you should have **also** checked the first minor's determinant is positive...which in this case is only $\;1>0\;$ and is trivial.

Comment: Thnx , if the matrix is of order higher then $2*2$ then it is neccessery to check the minor's determinent?

Comment: To be precise, you should say “$x^2+y^2-2axy > 0$ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your initially forgot the minuses in your matrix. 
Just note, as @DonAntonio mentioned, that you can't say your matrix is positive definite because its determinant is positive, you need to check the minors, too, which is trivial in this case ([Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)).

Otherwise the result and its derivation are correct.